# Query component parameters at runtime?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, alm

**How can I query the parameter names of the parameters of the component currently being executed?**

The first idea that comes to mind is to use the UFT automation object and query the `.BusinessComponent` property, like this:

```
Dim UFTApp: Set UFTApp=CreateObject ("QuickTest.Application")
Dim Index
Print "BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.Count=" & CStr (UFTApp.BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.Count)
For Index = 1 To UFTApp.BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.Count
    Print CStr (Index) & ": " & UFTApp.BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.Item (Index).Name
Next
```

Once I have the names, I can call `Parameter (<Name>)` to get the value. Alternatively, to also get the values, one could use

```
Print "BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.GetParameters.Count=" & CStr (UFTApp.BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.GetParameters.Count)
For Index = 1 To UFTApp.BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.GetParameters.Count
Print CStr (Index) & ": " & UFTApp.BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.GetParameters.Item (Index).Value
Next
```

This works fine if the component is executed standalone.

**But!** If you execute the component as part of a BPT, the `.Count` methods return zero.

It seems like the `ParameterDefinitions` collection is not set in this case. (Note `.BusinessComponent.Name` *does* return the correct value, so the container instance itself indeed is set properly.)

**So how can I iterate over the current component´s parameters if I don't know the parameter names in advance?**

This question comes up once you create generic library code that is not allowed to "know" the names in advance.

I am 99% sure the same question applies to QTP, so I included that tag, too.

Comment: It seems like the only way to accomplish this would be to use the QC/ALM API, and to query the values there. Which is by far too much of a hassle (and too expensive). So currently, I changed the concept a bit so I can predict the parameter names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the primary problem is that `BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions` is not set up properly, at least not in all cases.

To get the parameter definitions, we need to look into ALM´s API.

There, the main problem is that we do not know which component to query, i.e. we don´t know which is the currently running component.

The only reliable way I found to get the current component´s name (and ALM path) is to inspect `UFTApp.BusinessComponent.Location`. (`UFTApp.BusinessComponent.Name` is unreliable, because some versions of UFT seem to use the component ID to look up the component name in the test plan, which yields some (unpredictable) test´s name, and not the correct components name.)

So to enumerate the current component´s parameters, I now look up the component´s path (obtained from `.Location`) in ALM´s component folder factory, filter the resulting ALM folder so the filtered list only contains the component with the searched name (also obtained from `.Location`), and use ALM´s API to query the parameters.

That seems to work fine as long as you don´t use version control, or you make sure you check-in the change first after modifying parameters before you run below code.

Since the ALM API does not understand the `“[ALM] “` prefix that UFT wants (and which is included in the `BusinessComponent.Location` property value), some quick & dirty string parsing is required to build the path (or name) to search for.

Resulting code:

```
' Global shorthand for CreateObject ("QuickTest.Application") (UFT OTA-interface)
Dim UFTApp: Set UFTApp=GetObject ("","QuickTest.Application")


'@Description Name including path of current UFT component?
Public Function GetCurrentModuleName ()
    Dim Result: Result=GetUFTCurDoc.Location
    Result=Right (Result, Len (Result)-Len ("[ALM] "))
    GetCurrentModuleName=Result
End Function

'@Description Component name (without path) of the specified component?
'   ModuleName: Component name including ALM path
Public Function GetModuleName (ByVal ModuleName)
    ' Use split with backslash, then return only the last element
    Dim Parts: Parts=Split (ModuleName, "\", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
    GetModuleName=Parts(UBound (Parts))
End Function

'@Description ALM path of the specified componentname (including path) (returned value does not end with a backslash)?
'   ModuleName: Component name (including path) in ALM
Public Function GetModulePath (ByVal ModuleName)
    GetModulePath=Left (ModuleName, Len(ModuleName)-Len (GetModuleName (ModuleName))-1)
End Function


Dim ComponentFilter: Set ComponentFilter=QCUtil.QCConnection.ComponentFolderFactory.FolderByPath (GetModulePath (GetCurrentModuleName ())).ComponentFactory.Filter
ComponentFilter ("CO_NAME")="""" & GetModuleName (GetCurrentModuleName ()) & """"
Dim Param
For Each Param in ComponentFilter.NewList().Item(1).ComponentParamFactory.NewList("")
    Print Param.Name
Next
```

Since that answers  my original question perfectly, I´ll accept my own answer, as bad as this might look, so everybody with the same problem can use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using ALM + BPT, I executed a component several times with the below code and every time I get the correct parameters count. I also use the same component twice in the very same BPT.

```
UFTApp.BusinessComponent.ParameterDefinitions.Count
```

Were you getting 0 count all the time or just once in a while?

Comment: 0 all the time. This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Almost got the reputation for commenting. Thanks for the reminder.